# Let $I$ be a monomial ideal and let $f \in \mathbb{k}[x_1,...,x_n]$ then every term of $f \in I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $I$ be a monomial ideal and let $f \in \mathbb{k}[x_1,...,x_n]$ then porve that every term of $f \in I$.

I start with the following .

Let $f \in I$ .By the definition of monomial ideals we can write $f$ as $$f = \sum(h_i.x^{\alpha_i})...(1)$$

where $\alpha_i = (a_{i1},...,a_{in})$ and $x^{\alpha_i}=x_1^{a_{i1}}...x_n^{a_{in}}$ and $h_i \in \mathbb{k}[x_1,..x_n]$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

Also since $f$ is a polynomial we can write $f =p_ix^{\beta_i}...(2)$ where the definition is exactly the same as above and $p_i \in \mathbb{k}$.

Then , by grouping the similar terms in $(1)$ and $(2)$ and also by noticing the fact that $(1)=(2)$ we see that,

each of the terms in $(2)$ is some multiple of the terms in $(1)$,So from here I think we are able to conclude the above statement.

I get the idea of the satement but I think my proof is not clear.Can someone help me out please?

Comment: What exactly is the statement you're trying to proof? Would be great if you add more readability, e.g. adding some linebreaks

Comment: Is it better now ?